# Amazon Cognito facebook login on Angular 2

Tags: angular, facebook-login, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I am new to Amazon AWS cognito. can someone help to implement the facebook login on cognito. I have finished the steps give by cognito got logged in facebook and send that access token to cognito. Here is my code.

```
fblogin() {
    this.fb.login()

    .then((res: LoginResponse) => {
      console.log('cognito identitypole-->',CognitoUtil._IDENTITY_POOL_ID);
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: CognitoUtil._IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
            Logins: {
            'graph.facebook.com': res.authResponse.accessToken,                
            }                
        });            

    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

After this i dont have idea how to get registered in cognito using angular 2.

Any idea to implement facebook registration and login on cognito using angular 2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cognito have `User Pool` and `Federated Identities`. If you are using federated identities, it won't create a user in the `User Pool`

`Federated Identities` is like giving the user an access to your service without them having an account.

For Federated Sign in via AWS Amplify (client side)

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({
    domain,
    {
        token,
        identity_id, // Optional
        expires_at: expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime() // the expiration timestamp
    },
    user
}).
```

Link: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

I suggest using `AWS Amplify` for client side AWS Cognito usage.

If you want users to have an account to your user pool when they sign up via Facebook or Google, I think Cognito's Hosted UI supports it but if you have your own UI, you will have a different approach.
A question related to this: [Using Cognito User Pools, without Cognito Federated Identities(identity pools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023143/using-cognito-user-pools-without-cognito-federated-identitiesidentity-pools)