# How do I create a user in cognito user pool using social provider using c# code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I've been testing out using facebook to create amazon cognito users. I've been following the link below but from what I understand the examples are using client side code to register the user. What I need to be able to implement registration through my API so that I can apply business rules before the registration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html

This is my use case

- User starts registration, chooses facebook
- User goes through OAuth2 and provides permission
- mobile app initiates a server call with OAuth2 Tokens and user email
- Server creates a user in amazon cognito with the information from previous step

I've seen some examples but the ones I've been able to make work is related to identity pools and not user pools and the other is just using username and password.

Here is a related question we have the similar issue but my scenario is essentially not serverless.

[Using Cognito User Pools, without Cognito Federated Identities(identity pools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023143/using-cognito-user-pools-without-cognito-federated-identitiesidentity-pools)

Answer (score -1):

For that user pool that you want to create the user in.Go to Identity Providers under the Federation section of the user Pool, configure the Identity provider which in your case will be facebook. Then in the App Integration section choose App Client Settings a choose Facebook as one Enabled Identity Providers. The work flow will be as such when you register the facebook user and try to log in. It will automatically create a user in the user pool that matches that facebook user. Also remember to map the Claims in the Attribute Mapping Section.